# How does MySQL execute insert into ... select

Tags: mysql, insert

As I know that many single insert statement is so slow. It can be better by handling like below.

```
insert into table1 values(c1,c2,c3) values(c4,c5,c6).
```

I'm interested in how `insert into ... select ...` execute in MySQL. Are there any optimizations in it or Innodb? At last, my English is not so good.Sorry - -||.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
    INSERT INTO mytable (name, address, age)

     VALUES('raj', 'jaipur', '15'), 

    ('abc', 'india', '42'), 

    ('xyz', 'jaipur ', '29'), 

    ('taqi', 'Damsna', '32');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement executed by many `INSERT INTO ... VALUES(a1,b1,c1),(a2,b2,c2)` statement?

Comment: INSERT INTO mytable (name, address, age)

         VALUES('raj', 'jaipur', '15'), 

        ('abc', 'india', '42'), 

        ('xyz', 'jaipur ', '29'), 

        ('taqi', 'Damsna', '32'); This will insert multiple rows with single insert statement.

Comment: I have known that method. Is `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement executing insert operations by this method?